# why does using an NSString as a URL cause a SIGABRT?

Tags: objective-c

The following method causes the code to break, why is this? what is unique about an NSURL that they can't implicitly convert from NSString?

```
- (void)followLink
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
}
```

Comment: Pay proper attention to the API docs and the warnings / errors XCode gives you. Also, did you try debugging your code?

Comment: yes, it literally just says SIGABRT. very underwhelmed by XCode's ability to debug at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're passing `NSString` to the method that expects `NSURL` as parameter. To fix your problem create url object from your string:

```
- (void)followLink
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Comment: I get - `Class method '+urlWithString:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

Comment: @SirYakalot, ouch sorry - wrong letter capitalization in method name

Answer (score 0):

`openURL:` waits an `NSURL` object, you're giving it an `NSString`.

The code you were trying to write was probably:

```
- (void)followLink
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```